# Does Mandrill's Render API ignore merge_vars that map to Handlebars variables?

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, mandrill

On Mandrill's [Template API](https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/templates.JSON.html) page, I plug in the following JSON to test the [Render](https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/templates.JSON.html#method=render) method upon clicking "Try it":

```
{
    "key": "MY VALID KEY",
    "template_name": "test1",
    "template_content": [

    ],
    "merge_vars": [
        {
            "name": "invoice_number",
            "content": "1001"
        }
    ]
}
```

The test results come back with my template but the one `merge_var` I'm testing has not been merged, i.e. the result still contains `{{invoice_number}}`:

```
{
    "html": "<p style=\"font-family: sans-serif;\">Dear Customer,</p>\r\n\r\n<p style=\"font-family: sans-serif;\">Invoice {{invoice_number}} ...</p>"
}
```

Does Mandrill's Render API ignore `merge_vars` that map to Handlebars variables?

Comment: try using "global_merge_vars" rather than "merge_vars"

Comment: I just finished some tests and I think the API might be ignoring the variables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to Mandrill support:

> As you noticed, the render API call does not currently support
>   Handlebars templates. While I can't provide an exact ETA for when the
>   render API call will work with Handlebars, I can tell you that it's
>   something that our developers are working to extend support for very
>   soon.
>
> I would suggest keeping an eye on our [Mandrill API Documentation](https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/)
>   as that support will be noted there as an additional parameter for the
>   call as soon as it is supported.

Comment: Bummer, render(..) still does not support merge_language parameter.

Comment: It's now clearly stated in documentation, that per-recipient merge variables override global merge variables with the same name, but when POSTing json with  vars the variable is still empty in my template.  merge_vars: [
      {
        "rcpt": "me@gmail.com",
        "vars": [
          {
            "name": "firstName",
            "content": "firstName"
          } } ] Global vars work fine. What could be the case?